# Confusing overload resolution

Tags: c#, overload-resolution

I have a class that inherits from another class to allow using nullable value. But when I use it with non-nullable value​​, it uses the overload anyway for nullable.

I do not understand why the function of the class c2 mask the function of the class c1 in this code :

```
class c1
{
    public void fn1(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("value {0} is normal", value);
    }
    public void fn1(int? value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("value {0} is nullable", value);
    }
    public void fn2(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("value {0} is normal", value);
    }
}
class c2: c1
{
    public void fn2(int? value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("value {0} is nullable", value);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        c1 o1 = new c1();
        c2 o2 = new c2();
        int val = 10;
        o1.fn1(val);
        o2.fn1(val);
        o2.fn2(val);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And the result is :

```
value 10 is normal.
value 10 is normal.
value 10 is nullable.
```

However c2 has function fn2(int).

Comment: sometimes you can disambiguate this with a cast. If your fn2 functions were swapped then calling with a cast will chose the correct function o2.fn2((int?)val);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found on Jon Skeet's blog.

> Inheritance can cause a confusing effect. When the compiler goes
>   looking for instance method overloads, it considers the compile-time
>   class of the "target" of the call, and looks at methods declared
>   there. If it can't find anything suitable, it then looks at the parent
>   class... then the grandparent class, etc. This means that if there are
>   two methods at different levels of the hierarchy, the "deeper" one
>   will be chosen first, even if it isn't a "better function member" for
>   the call.

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As is true in many edge cases, there's no divined "why" to it, it's just how the C# spec was written.  They could have done it other ways, but decided to do it this way. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx

Most relevant portion (from "7.4.2 Overload resolution" of C# spec linked above, different versions of spec may have similar text in other section):

> the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include ... methods in a base class are not candidates **if any method in a derived class is applicable**

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of your functions follows your class hierarchy.  In the example you posted function c2::fn2 matches your call o2.fn2(val) because it has been explicitly defined in c2 and the compiler can implicitly covert int to int?  In effect you have hidden c1::fn2.

You can look at making your c1 class abstract (sans implementation) or virtual with override in c2.

Answer (score 0):

Like say Handoko.Chen, on Jon Skeet's blog we can find

> The compiler ignores the overriding method in the child.

So the only way I found is to hide inherit method :

```
class c2: c1 {
    public void fn2(int? value) {
        Console.WriteLine("value {0} is nullable", value);
    }
    public new void fn2(int value) {
        base.fn2(value);
    }
}
```